# Exception handling in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In the following code  i want to get list of everything that failed in `rescue`

```
puts "Verifying Home Page"
  begin   
    page.find('#logoAnchor')
    puts "logo anchor found"
    page.find('.navbar-inner')
    puts "Header bar found"
    page.find('.unstyled')
    puts "Found occations frame"
    page.find('#easyPrintPromoBox')
    puts "Easy Print Frame Found!"
    page.find('.tabbable')
    puts "3 Tabs  Found!"
    page.find('#givingCardPromoBox')
    puts "Create Frame Found!"
    page.find('.footer')
    puts "Footer Found!"

  rescue
    puts "Logo anchor not Found"
  end
```

Here i only catch the exception if logo anchor not found.I have to catch exceptions if any one of them not found.
for eg:

if logo anchor not found  puts "logo anchor not present " in `rescue`
    if header bar not present puts"header bar not found" in `rescue`

Comment: `rescue` will capture the first exception that is thrown. You want to get a list of everything that failed?

Comment: yes i want to get list of everything that failed

Comment: Then you have to wrap every statement that can raise an exception in a `begin...rescue...end` block.

Comment: ... By wrapping every statement in a begin/rescue/end block? Although I might wrap that up in a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using `Array#partition`

```
# dummy placeholder method for `page.find`
def find(el)
  if rand < 0.5
    raise :nop
  else
    true
  end
end

selectors = ['#logoAnchor', '.navbar-inner', '.unstyled', '#easyPrintPromoBox', '.tabbable', '#givingCardPromoBox', '.footer']
found, not_found = selectors.partition do |selector|
  find(selector) rescue false
end

puts "Found: #{found}"
puts "Not found: #{not_found}"
```

Sample output:

```
Found: ["#logoAnchor", ".unstyled", "#easyPrintPromoBox", ".tabbable"]
Not found: [".navbar-inner", "#givingCardPromoBox", ".footer"]
```

This should work in Capybara (not tested):

```
selectors = ['#logoAnchor', '.navbar-inner', '.unstyled', '#easyPrintPromoBox', '.tabbable', '#givingCardPromoBox', '.footer']
found, not_found = selectors.partition do |selector|
  page.find(selector) rescue false
end

puts "Found: #{found}"
puts "Not found: #{not_found}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
puts "Verifying Home Page"
  begin   
    page.find('#logoAnchor')
    puts "logo anchor found"
  rescue
    puts "Logo anchor not Found"
  end

  begin   
    page.find('#navbar-inner')
    puts "navbar-inner found"
  rescue
    puts "navbar-inner not Found"
  end

  ...
  end
```

or

```
def findOrRescue(id, successMsg, errorMsg)
   begin   
    page.find(id)
    puts successMsg
   rescue
    puts errorMsg
   end
end

 puts "Verifying Home Page"
   findOrRescue("#logoAnchor", "logo anchor found", "Logo anchor not Found")
   ...
```